# Using Java blogger API v3 to post on blog dynamically

Tags: java, google-api, google-oauth, blogger, google-api-java-client

I have two issues regarding using Java blogger API v3 to dynamically posting posts to my blogger account.

First

I used the following code to get credential for accessing my blog:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)                
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId(emailAddress)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
                new File(p12FileLocation))
                .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(BloggerScopes.BLOGGER))
                .build();

        credential.setAccessToken("zRLqmkM82626Uym9Uv1Jsdd");


        Blogger blogger = new Blogger.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName("Blogger")
                .build();
        // .... rest of the code to prepare post and send it ......
```

I set the access token above (credential.setAccessToken) that was generated from the following google page: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground

but this token is expired every 3600 seconds. so I visit the page again and press the button "Refresh access token" to get another one and use it again in above code.

**Is this the correct method of accessing my blog and dynamically posting contents and articles programmatically?**

Second

In google developers console https://developers.google.com/console i saw that I have 10000 requests/day and a limit of 1 request/second/user

BUT

after correctly posting dynamically using my above code around 50 posts (note that I set a wait for around 5 seconds between a consecutive requests), I started receiving the following error from the api call:

```
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "usageLimits",
    "message" : "Rate Limit Exceeded",
    "reason" : "rateLimitExceeded"
  } ],
  "message" : "Rate Limit Exceeded"
}
```

I return to my quota page and I see that the requests that I send did not decreased from my allowed requests per day !!!

Some my second question is:

**Does I forget a specific configuration for correctly manipulate my blog dynamically ?**

Thank you in advance for your help and support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to preauthorize someone for Blogger so I believe the only way to access Blogger Api is to generate access token through Auth 2 Playground and then using the token for API call.

Even though it shows 10000 requests/day and a limit of 1 request/second/user on the console, the fact is Blogger api only permit maximum 50 requests per day by default. Till a while back there was provision to request additional quota by specifying genuine need for it which has now been discontinued.

Comment: This is wrong. I have done a huge number of blogger API requests per day free of cost. I have never managed to exceed the quota!

Comment: It should be 10000 requests/day. I've displayed a live leader board which updates every minute in my blog with the below code. (appx. 1,440 requests per day). However I had to refresh my api token once in an hour.

Answer (score 3):

You can generate the api token through your code instead of generating it from the playground. However you have to authenticate on the first time.

```
private static GoogleCredential getCredentials(HttpTransport httpTransport, JacksonFactory jacksonFactory,
        List<String> scopes) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, jacksonFactory,
            CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, scopes).setAccessType("online").setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();
    String url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).build();
    System.out.println("Please open the following URL in your " + "browser then type the authorization code:");
    System.out.println("  " + url);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String code = br.readLine();
    GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
    System.out.println("Response : " + response.toPrettyString());
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(jacksonFactory).setServiceAccountId("xyz@gmail.com")
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("resources\\xyz.p12"))
            .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(BloggerScopes.BLOGGER)).build();
    credential.setAccessToken(response.getAccessToken());
    return credential;
}

public static Blogger getBlog() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, AuthenticationException {
    if (blog == null) {
        if (httpTransport == null)
            httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        if (jacksonFactory == null)
            jacksonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        blog = new Blogger.Builder(httpTransport, jacksonFactory,
                getCredentials(httpTransport, jacksonFactory, Arrays.asList(BloggerScopes.BLOGGER)))
                        .setApplicationName("Blogger").build();
    }
    return blog;
}

public static void udpatePost(String title, String content) throws IOException, AuthenticationException, GeneralSecurityException{
    Post post = new Post();
    post.setTitle(title);
    post.setContent(content);
    Update updateAction = getBlog().posts().update(BLOG_ID, POST_ID, post);
    updateAction.setFields("author/displayName,content,published,title,url");
    post = updateAction.execute();
    System.out.println("Published: " + post.getPublished());  
}
```

JARs for API v3 Client Library: http://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/api-lib/java

Comment: Please let me know the value of REDIRECT_URI=?

Comment: you can give anything.. say http://example.com On success, it'll redirect there..