# SessionExpiredException occured when trying to create a post using Google Blogger API OAuth2

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, blogger, google-api-java-client

I am using the below code to update an existing blog post. I'm getting SessionExpiredException. What am I doing wrong?

```
    GoogleService service = new BloggerService("MyBloggerIntegration-v1");        
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            httpTransport, jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET,
            Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger"))
            .setAccessType("offline")               
            .setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();

    String url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).build();
    System.out.println("Please open the following URL in your "
            + "browser then type the authorization code:");
    System.out.println("  " + url);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String code = br.readLine();
    GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();        
    System.out.println("Response : "+response.toPrettyString());
    service.setOAuth2Credentials(new GoogleCredential().setFromTokenResponse(response));

     Entry myEntry = new Entry();
     myEntry.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct(title));
     myEntry.setContent(new PlainTextConstruct(content));
     URL postUrl = new URL("http://www.blogger.com/feeds/" + blogID + "/posts/default/"+postID);
     service.update(postUrl, myEntry);
```

Output :

```
 Please open the following URL in your browser then type the authorization code:
 https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&approval_prompt=auto&client_id=67330569820-unio63db63ljnloc1hd52bvcoj8g8vrr.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://cegcodingcamp.blogspot.in&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger
 4/d_1GaJe4lHpOdRmhidwWgC7_utKoqfbwXnfYoP2hR_c#
 Response : {
    "access_token" : "ya29.MQJqQi7HqTcJGoCCU-Lo5Ybdb1Otc-Z_fsAN97oySVsU84A7IXr_cPqWcrMe2raZoSvU",
    "expires_in" : 3591,
    "token_type" : "Bearer"
 }
 Exception in thread "main" com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService$SessionExpiredException: Unauthorized
 User does not have permission to edit object

at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:570)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.update(Service.java:1563)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.update(Service.java:1530)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.update(GoogleService.java:604)
at line service.update(postUrl, myEntry)
```

I also tried the following methods

Method 2:

```
    service = new GoogleService("blogger", "exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory jacksonFactory = com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(jacksonFactory)
            .setServiceAccountId("xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com")
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("resources/xxxx.p12"))
            .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger"))
            .build();
    service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
```

Method 3:

```
    service = new GoogleService("blogger", "exampleCo-exampleApp-1");           
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    List<String> collection = new ArrayList<String>();
    collection.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger");

    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)                
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setServiceAccountId("xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com")
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
              new File("resources\\xxxx.p12"))
            .setServiceAccountScopes(collection)
            .build();

    credential.setAccessToken("ya29.MQJqQi7HqTcJGoCCU-Lo5Ybdb1Otc-Z_fsAN97oySVsU84A7IXr_cPqWcrMe2raZoSvU");
    service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
```

But I am getting the same exception.

Comment: Yes.. Check the exception in the output.

Comment: 2 and 3 wont work.  Service accounts arnt supported with blogger.   Why are you using the V2 of blogger api why not use V3 version?   https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/api-lib/java

Comment: Thank you for the link. After importing the jars you linked, this worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115446/using-java-blogger-api-v3-to-post-on-blog-dynamically/33881103#33881103

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like V2 of Blogger API is not supported. We have to use V3 API.

Import Jars after dowloading :  http://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/api-lib/java

Then follow this answer : [Using Java blogger API v3 to post on blog dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115446/using-java-blogger-api-v3-to-post-on-blog-dynamically/33881103#33881103)